# Swift - Append to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to append to an NSMutableDictionary with the following code:

```
let RSVPDirectory = NSMutableDictionary()

            for i in 0..<self.RSVPs.count {

                var tmp = self.RSVPs[i]

                var firstLetter = String()

                if(tmp["lastname"] is NSNull)
                {
                    firstLetter = ((tmp["email"] as? NSString)?.substring(to: 1).uppercased())!
                }
                else
                {
                    firstLetter = ((tmp["lastname"] as? NSString)?.substring(to: 1).uppercased())!
                }

                if RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] == nil {
                    RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] = [AnyHashable]()
                }

                RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] = tmp
            }
```

My problem with this is that I am expecting multiple tmp inside RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] but it only adds the first one as if its overriding the previous tmp

How do I append to NSMutableDictionary in swift, I know in objective-c you can do this:

```
[[RSVPDirectory objectForKey:firstLetter] addObject:tmp];
```

What would be the equivalent to that in swift?

Comment: [addObject:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411274-addobject) is clearly the `instance` method of `NSMutableArray`. But your are talking about `NSMutableDictionary`. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: **Do not use `NSMutableArray` / `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift**. And do not use that weird `NSString` syntax. This is Swift, there is much better API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are actually replacing the `RSVPDirectory[firstLetter]`, overriding it every time with new `tmp`.

What you are looking for is this:

```
//RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] = tmp //Replace this line with below code
let tempArray = RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] as? [AnyHashable]
tempArray?.append(tmp)
RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] = tmpArray
```

Here I have used a `tempArray` because we want to mutate the array. Accessing it directly and trying to append new value will in-turn try to mutate an immutable value. So first I have got the array in the `tempArray` and then after mutating the array I swapped it back in the dictionary with updated values.

Comment: I get this error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[AnyHashable]'

Comment: see my edit. I have tried it, it should work for you too.

Comment: I get a new error `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>' (0x10fed4110) to 'Swift.AnyHashable'`

Comment: On this line: tempArray?.append(tmp as! AnyHashable)

Comment: what is the type of the content in `RSVPs[]`? if it is Dictionary<String,Any> then you should use Dictionary<String,Any> instead of AnyHashable

Answer (score 2):

This is the native Swift version of your *Objective-C-ish* code.

It uses the `Dictionary(grouping` API of Swift 4

```
let RSVPDirectory = Dictionary(grouping: RSVPs) { (dictionary) -> String in
    if let lastName = dictionary["lastname"] as? String {
        return String(lastName.prefix(1).uppercased())
    } else if let email = dictionary["email"] as? String {
        return String(email.prefix(1).uppercased())
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code in a playground you will see the output, hope this gives you an idea.

```
func upperCaseFirstLetter(_ str: String) -> String {
    guard let first = str.first else { return "" }
    return "\(first)".uppercased()
}

var RSVPs = [[String:String]]()
var RSVPDirectory = [String: [[String:String]]]()

//Test Data
var str = ["email":"test1@c.com"]
RSVPs.append(str)
str = ["lastname":"Atest2"]
RSVPs.append(str)


for i in 0..<RSVPs.count {
    var tmp = RSVPs[i]
    var firstLetter = ""

    if(tmp["lastname"] == nil) {

        firstLetter = upperCaseFirstLetter(tmp["email"]!)
    } else {
        firstLetter = upperCaseFirstLetter(tmp["lastname"]!)
    }

    if RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] == nil {
        RSVPDirectory[firstLetter] = [[String:String]]()
    }

    RSVPDirectory[firstLetter]?.append(tmp)
}

print(RSVPDirectory)
```